# Перехват всех клавиш внутри всего приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Как перехватить нажатия кнопок клавиатуры внутри **всего приложения**, независимо от того какое окно приложения открыто в данный момент (даже MessageDialog). 
Хуки не устраивают, мне не нужны клавишы чужого приложения.

**UPD:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  private void LoadedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Window w = sender as Window;
    w.PreviewKeyDown += delegate (object subSender, KeyEventArgs se) {   /*!!!*/ };
  }

  public App() : base()
  {
    Style winDefaultStyle = new Style() { TargetType = typeof(Window) };
    winDefaultStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(Window.LoadedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)LoadedEvent));
    Window.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(winDefaultStyle, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
  }
}
```

Ну в краце как-то так... Однако я не могу перехватить окна диалогов... Но уже что-то.

Comment: PreviewKeyDown на уровне окна? С MessageBox'ами, боюсь, не прокатит (но там почти не нужна клавиатура).

Comment: @VladD, накидал некий пример, что смог соорудить, однако мне нужно перехватывать и кнопки диалогов. Пока не понял как...

Comment: Ну, смотря о каких диалогах идёт речь. Если диалог ваш (построен на `Window`), то должно работать. А если у вас есть `MessageBox`, замените его на самописный диалог, построенный на `Window`.